# Nodejs splitting string

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let NewName= params.strdocumentname + "(" + results.rows[0].arrayfilecount+ ")";
strdocumentname = params.strdocumentname = NewName;
```

the current output is **Jayson.png(2)**

desired output **Jayson (2).png**

How do i do that using the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:-

```
const path = require('path');
const extension= path.extname(params.strdocumentname);
const name= params.strdocumentname.replace(extension,"(" + results.rows[0].arrayfilecount+ ")");
const newName = name + extension;
```

Hope it helps
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your `params.strdocumentname` contains the extension of the file also.
Try this code;

```
let [fileName, extension] = params.strdocumentname.split('.');
let NewName= fileName + "(" + results.rows[0].arrayfilecount+ ")." + extension;
strdocumentname = params.strdocumentname = NewName;
```

see working fiddle

```js
let mockFileName = "abc.png"
let mockArrayCount = '1'

let [fileName, extension] = mockFileName.split('.');
let NewName= fileName + "(" + mockArrayCount+ ")." + extension;

console.log(NewName)
alert(NewName)
```